# Magento hide date when value is 2010-01-01 00:00:00

Tags: date

I use a custom date attribute to display a date.
By default the attribute does have value 2010-01-01 or does not have any value (empty attribute).

I need are rule that checks if the date is the default value of 2010-01-01 or empty, then it should echo nothing.

Else it should echo some of this code, except the first if rule:

```
<?php if($_product->getData('nieuwe_voorraad')) : ?>
    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php
$today = Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($_product->getData('nieuwe_voorraad'));
$date = Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($today, Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_FULL, false);
echo $date;
?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: declare this $today = '2015-03-28';

Comment: @Kothari It should hide the default value when the value is 2010-01-01

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand..   do you simple need an if statement that skips output if the data matches your pattern or is blank?   I have not tested this code, but if your request is as simple as I think it is, try this:

```
<?php 

    $data = $_product->getData('nieuwe_voorraad');
    if((trim($data) != '2010-01-01') && (trim($data) != ''){ ?>
        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php
        $today = Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($_product->getData('nieuwe_voorraad'));
        $date = Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($today, Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_FULL, false);
        echo $date; ?></p><?php 
    } ?>
```